# How do I loop posts for a custom category for a custom post type in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

The code I have below loops all posts within one of my custom post types.
 I need to loop for a specific category within the custom post type.

```
<?php 
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'case-study' ) ); 
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'work' ); 

         endwhile;
    endif; 
?>
```

What do I need to change for it it loop a specified category within the custom post type?

Comment: Try `'post_type_cat' => 'your category'` or `$query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=your category' );` or `$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=1' );`

Comment: Ok I will give this a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'case-study',          // name of post type.
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',   // taxonomy name
            'field' => 'term_id',           // term_id, slug or name
            'terms' => 48,                  // term id, term slug or term name
        )
    )
) );
```

Comment: This is working for me. Thank you so much my friend.